# couldn't get a good image quality when used DOM to Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-to-image

I'm working on a meme editor web app using [DOM to image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library and [FileSaver.JS](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to save the image.

Saving the image using the PC screen is somewhat good, but when it's saved using the phone screen the image that shows up is a pixelated image.

Here is the `div` that I need to save:

```
       <div class="col-md-6">

            <div id="theUserMeme">

                <div class="row">
    
                    <p id="memeWords">
                        People struggles with making memes for free <br>
                        Instant Memes:
                    </p>
    
                </div>
    
                <div class="row">
                    <img id = "memeImage" src="images/init meme.jpg">
                </div>
    
            </div>
    

        </div>
```

Also, here is my code for the function that saves the image:

```
function generateMeme(){

var options = {
    quality: 1,
};

var alertMsg = "*********** Please Read *********** \n";
alertMsg += "Image must be saved in your device \n";
alertMsg += "If you didn't get the image that you want try again, otherwise, feel free to get in touch with us \n";
alertMsg += "*********** Thanks for reading ***********";

domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('theUserMeme'), options)
.then(function (blob) {
    
    alert(alertMsg);
    window.saveAs(blob, 'instant meme.jpeg');
});

}
```

Also, here is my CSS code for the parts of the meme:

```
    #memeWords{

    font-size: 25px;
}

#theUserMeme{


    background-color: white;
}
```

What the issue could be? Why it is happening? How to fix it?